# Save customer custom attribute image in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, module, customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

When I am save customer custom attribute image from frontend, it should be save in location but not shown in frontend. It shows the broken URL

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
$customer = $this->getCustomerSession()->getCustomer();

if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() 
        && isset($_FILES['company_logo']['name']) 
        && ($_FILES['company_logo']['name'] != '')) {
    try {
        $customer->setCompanyLogo($_FILES['company_logo']['name'])->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
}
```

I am waiting from last one day. any Comments would be appreciate

Thanks